# How could I use abstract class on spring framework?

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I'm the one leaning how to write a code using Spring Boot. Then when I tried to write a code that used abstract class, I got an error as below.

```
Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.in28minutes.spring.practice.springmasterclasspractice.devicefactory.LaptopManufacturingProcess required a bean of type 'java.lang.String' that could not be found.

Action:
Consider defining a bean of type 'java.lang.String' in your configuration.
```

Could you guys give me an advise how I could solve the error?

Spring Boot: v2.1.4
Java: 10.0.2
Maven: 3.6.0

`SpringMasterClassPracticeDeviceFactoryApplication` class

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringMasterClassPracticeDeviceFactoryApplication {

    private static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SpringMasterClassPracticeDeviceFactoryApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext = SpringApplication
                .run(SpringMasterClassPracticeDeviceFactoryApplication.class, args);
        ManufacturingImpl manufacturingImpl = applicationContext.getBean(ManufacturingImpl.class);

        System.out.println(manufacturingImpl);
        // manufacturingImpl.manifactureProduct("Laptop Process");

        LOGGER.info("{}", manufacturingImpl);

    }

}
```

`ManufacturingImpl` class

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class ManufacturingImpl {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("laptop")
    private GeneralManufacturingProcess generalManufacturingProcess;

    public void manifactureProduct(String processName) {
        System.out.println(generalManufacturingProcess);
        generalManufacturingProcess.launchProcess();
    }
}
```

`GeneralManufacturingProcess` class

```
public abstract class GeneralManufacturingProcess {

    private String processName;

    public GeneralManufacturingProcess(String processName) {
        this.processName = processName;
    }

    public String getProcessName() {
        return processName;
    }

    public void launchProcess() {
        if (processName != null && !processName.isEmpty()) {
            assembleDevice();
            testDevice();
            packageDevice();
            storeDevice();
        } else {
            System.out.println("No process name was specified");
        }
    }

    protected abstract void assembleDevice();

    protected abstract void testDevice();

    protected abstract void packageDevice();

    protected abstract void storeDevice();
}
```

`LaptopManufacturingProcess` class

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Qualifier("laptop")
public class LaptopManufacturingProcess extends GeneralManufacturingProcess {

    public LaptopManufacturingProcess(String processName) {
        super(processName);
    }

    @Override
    protected void assembleDevice() {
        System.out.println("Assembled laptop: " + getProcessName());
    }

    @Override
    protected void testDevice() {
        System.out.println("Tested laptop: " + getProcessName());
    }

    @Override
    protected void packageDevice() {
        System.out.println("Packaged laptop: " + getProcessName());
    }

    @Override
    protected void storeDevice() {
        System.out.println("Stored laptop: " + getProcessName());
    }
}
```

Comment: The exception tells you exactly what is wrong and it has nothing to do with an abstract super class... Your `LaptopManufacturingProcess` has a constructor that needs a `String`. YOu don't have another bean in  your configuration of type `String`. What you probably want is, to ditch the annotations on the `LaptopManufacturingProcess` and instead create an `@Bean` method named `laptop` in  your `SpringMasterClassPracticeDeviceFactoryApplication` which calls the constructor with the appropratie `String`.

Comment: What `processName` you want to use for `laptop` bean?

Comment: It seems you're trying to parameterize `LaptopManufacturingProcess` by constructor. _Most_ spring beans are singletons. Move your `processName` parameter to the `launchProcess` call and keep track of it as a local variable throughout.

Answer (score 1):

There are Multiple ways to solve this. The problem is, that the Spring Framework is trying to create an instance of LaptopManufacturingProcess with the single constructor, which accepts a String. So the Framework is trying to autowire a Bean of type String into the constructor, which simply does not work.
Basically, what you can do is the following:

- create a no-args constructor, and have it pass a hardcoded string to the parent constructor:

```
public LaptopManufacturingProcess() {
  super("String");
}
```

- Add an @Value-Annotation to read the String from a PropertySource:

```
public LaptopManufacturingProcess(@Value("${property.key.here}") String processName) {
  super(processName);
}
```

- Create a Factory Bean to create instances of `GeneralManufacturingProcess` on demand